# How to get certain elements using jsonpath + Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jsonpath

I have a file named source.json, the content is

```
{
    "msg": "OK",
    "result": {
        "data": {
            "articles": [
                {
                    "idtArticle": "CF00002",
                    "promotionService": {
                        "bundleSales": [
                            {
                                "code": "201900001"
                            },
                            {
                                "code": "201900002"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "idtArticle": "CF00003",
                    "promotionService": {
                        "bundleSales": [
                            {
                                "code": "201900001"
                            },
                            {
                                "code": "201900003"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have Python code as following:

```
import json
import jsonpath

json_source = 'source.json'

with open(json_source, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    root = json.loads(f.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = jsonpath.jsonpath(root, """$..articles[?(@.idtArticle == "CF00002")]""")
    print(result)
```

The code works and I can get the article whose idtArticle is CF00002, but how to get the article list whose code(or one of the 2 codes) is 201900001?

Appreciate all the helps!

Comment: Your json is invalid, there are two trailling commas after "code": "201900001" and "code": "201900003". See https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @StaticX yes and thanks, let me correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonpath` **does not support projections** so I would do what you want in simple python.

```
import json

json_source = 'source.json'
with open(json_source, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    root = json.loads(f.read())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    articles = root['result']['data']['articles']
    result = []
    for article in articles:
        bundleSales = article['promotionService']['bundleSales']
        for bundleSale in bundleSales:
            if bundleSale['code'] == "201900001":
                result.append(article['idtArticle'])
    print(result)
```

You can test it with an extended example:

```
{
    "msg": "OK",
    "result": {
        "data": {
            "articles": [
                {
                    "idtArticle": "CF00002",
                    "promotionService": {
                        "bundleSales": [
                            {
                                "code": "201900001"
                            },
                            {
                                "code": "201900002"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "idtArticle": "CF00003",
                    "promotionService": {
                        "bundleSales": [
                            {
                                "code": "201900001"
                            },
                            {
                                "code": "201900003"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "idtArticle": "CF00004",
                    "promotionService": {
                        "bundleSales": [
                            {
                                "code": "201900002"
                            },
                            {
                                "code": "201900003"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

It prints ['CF00002', 'CF00003'].